# In hibernate is there a way to retrieve a list of entities ordered by a property of a many-to-one relationship object

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, many-to-one

I have a many-to-one relationship as follows

```
    <hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false" package="com.my.sample.data">
  <class name="Person" table="person_table">
<!-- other stuff -->
 <many-to-one class="Company" column="p_id" fetch="join" insert="false" name="company" update="false" not-found="ignore" not-null="false" />
```

Company maps to company_table and has a property company_id. Is there a way to fetch a list of Person ordered by Company.company_id via hibernate. So when I query

```
  items = (List<A>) getSession().createCriteria(Person.class)                        
                        .add(Restrictions.in("person_id", pIds)
                        ).list();
```

So I end up with a list of Person ordered by company_id.
The only addOrder syntax I found took a property name like

```
addOrder(Order.asc("person_id").`
```

I could not find how to refer to a property name of a foreign object something akin to

```
addOrder.Order.asc("company.company_id")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will help. Base on the Criteria theory. Criteria cannot do implicit join. so we make it explicit.

Example:

```
items = (List<A>) getSession().createCriteria(Person.class)                        
                        .add(Restrictions.in("person_id", pIds)
                        .createCriteria("company")
                        .addOrder("company_id");
                        ).list();
```

Hope this useful for you.